# How to change the root branch that was branched off of

Tags: git

Let's say I have a `master` and `develop` branch. `develop` has code that `master` doesn't. I branch off of `develop` and create `feature`, write some new code, merge it into `develop` (to put it on staging and test it). I then decide I want to merge `feature` into `master`, but includes everything from `develop` that's not in master, which I don't want to merge right now. How can I make it so that `feature` has the code I added, as if it was branched from `master`, and not `develop`? I've been reading a bit about rebase, and cherry-pick, but I can see any examples exactly like mine (where `feature` has already been merged into `develop`)

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
git rebase --onto master develop feature
```

and then merge that into master

```
git merge master
```

you may create intermediate branch names if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of commit(s) from `develop` branch.

1. `git checkout develop`
2. `git log` and get the commit `hash-number`.

Sample commit `hash-number`:
`commit 0ef6a22f4a4bd1dc4561dab413a9ff09780d18c0`

After getting the commit hash(es). Checkout master and cherry pick the commits from `develop` to `master` one by one. Prefer to go from older commits to the newer, to avoid more merge conflicts.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git cherry-pick hash-number`